# How a initialize columns value in pandas as a unique

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am trying to initialize Column Value as a Unique as I want to create a plot depends on a Unique column values and a Date Column....

as I find these error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mwx825326/PycharmProjects/MyReference/myGUI.py", line 19, in <module>
    availble_cell = gsm_kpis['CellName'].unique()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

in this line:

```
availble_cell = gsm_kpis['CellName'].unique()
```

and this is my `pandas.read_sql`:

```
gsm_kpis = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027]',
                       engine).to_dict(orient='records')
```

How can I solve this error....??

Comment: gsm_kpis is a list of dictionaries, not a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `gsm_kpis` isn't a DataFrame, but a list of dict.

If you instead do

```
gsm_kpis = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[mnm_rotterdam_5_daily_details-20191216081027]',
                       engine)
```

then you will have a DataFrame and

```
availble_cell = gsm_kpis['CellName'].unique()
```

will work